# Change NSAttributedText from UITextfield to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm using a TextField and TextView, for each fields I am assigning attributed String values. While I am changing the attributed string from UITextField to UITextView, the attributed strings are not aligning Properly.

Check the screen shot attached.## [image: Heading] ##

from the screen shot here I had used a UILabel, UITextView and UITextfield. While copying the attributed text of more than one line from UITextField to UITextView is displaying like the above (screen shot) in UITextView with dots.  Also not able to type in the textView, whereas as in UILabel it works good. Is there any property I need to add for UITextView.

Comment: Provide details about how the text view is setup and show some relevant code in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy just i had implemented basic UITextview and UITextField. The difference is instead of using string i used attributed string for both UITextView and UITextField.